# Swift: using "self" to target parent ViewController in public functions?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I want to create "Components" to add them to the UI, defining them in public functions like:

```
public func addBackground () {
var myWhiteView = UIView()
        myWhiteView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.width, 30)
        myWhiteView.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

        self.view.addSubview(myWhiteView)
        println("added white")
    }

}
```

Obviously if I am not in a UIViewController class, use of self. is not allowed/possible. How do i target the parent ViewController whoever this might be later on?

Comment: you can pass the reference of the parent view to this function addBackground (view:UIView)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let the function accept a parameter of `UIView` type:

```
public func addBackground (view: UIView) {
    var myWhiteView = UIView()
    myWhiteView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, view.frame.width, 30)
    myWhiteView.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

    view.addSubview(myWhiteView)
    println("added white")
}
```

Change the parameter to `UIViewController` if you really need to work on a view controller, otherwise I suggest leaving `UIView` as it is more generic and you can use with any view.

As an alternate solution, you might want to consider adding an extension instead, to either `UIView`:

```
extension UIView {
    public func addBackground () {
        var myWhiteView = UIView()
        myWhiteView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.width, 30)
        myWhiteView.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

        self.addSubview(myWhiteView)
        println("added white")
    }
}
```

or `UIViewController`:

```
extension UIViewController {
    public func addBackground () {
        var myWhiteView = UIView()
        myWhiteView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.width, 30)
        myWhiteView.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

        self.view.addSubview(myWhiteView)
        println("added white")
    }
}
```